# How to loop over an array of colors to change background on key(press/down)

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop, background-color

Internet. Forgive me if this isn't somehow more relevant to others but I'll leave this here in case it's a valid question.

I am trying to create a textarea field in which every time and anytime the user presses a key (a-z), it will trigger a background color change (listed in an array). I've been doing this with JQuery and I think I'm close(?) but every time I run my code and press a key, the last item in the array is the only color that comes up. I thought to use a conditional with the for loop, but I wouldn't know where to put it--if it's even necessary. What am I doing wrong? Also, should I set "x = color[0]" instead?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colors = ["#FFF0CB", "#FFECD1", "#FFE9DA", "#FFE7E4"];
    $("textarea").keydown(function() {
        for (x = 0; x < colors.length; x++;) {
            $("textarea").css("background-color", colors[x]);
        };
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](//jsfiddle.net/filmonmerid/6ztmdbja/3/)

Comment: You all have very valid answers! I just went with the first response. Thank you for showing me a subtle variety of ways of coding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping through and setting all the colors in single key press. Browser might be optimizing it to display the final background, or maybe it's switching so fast that you can't see it.

You should store the index of current background somewhere and just switch to the next instead of looping:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ["#FFF0CB", "#FFECD1", "#FFE9DA", "#FFE7E4"];
  var index = 0;
  $("textarea").keydown(function() {
    if (index >= colors.length)
      index = 0; // reset back to first color
    $("textarea").css("background-color", colors[index]);
    index++;
  });
});
```

Comment: Huh, I totally thought that a for loop was necessary considering there's still a variable (index) which shouldn't exceed the number of items in an array (index < colors.length) and incrementing that variable (index++). I guess that shows the extent of my logic :P Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a global variable and increment it each time you press a key

```
  var colors = ["#FFF0CB", "#FFECD1", "#FFE9DA", "#FFE7E4"];
            var index = 0;
            $("textarea").keydown(function() {
                    $("textarea").css("background-color", colors[index]);
                    index = index >= colors.length?0:index+1;//if end of array reset variable to 0

            });
```

```js
     var colors = ["#FFF0CB", "#FFECD1", "#FFE9DA", "#FFE7E4"];
        var index = 0;
        $("textarea").keydown(function() {
                $("textarea").css("background-color", colors[index]);
                index = index >= colors.length?0:index+1;//if end of array reset variable to 0
                
        });
```

```css
textarea{
  outline:none;
  border:none;
  resize: none;
  width: 400px;
  height:400px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
      <textarea placeholder="Pssst! Type your message here!"></textarea>
</body>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/02yfyp86/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a for loop. You have just to upcount x every time the user press a key. Then it will work. 
Don't forget to reset x to 0 if you reach the end of array

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I have some other code that is fired when the key is pressed and this logic will definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var colors = ["#FFF0CB", "#FFECD1", "#FFE9DA", "#FFE7E4"];
var length = colors.length;
$(document).ready(function() {
var x = 0
$("textarea").keydown(function() {
$("textarea").css("background-color", colors[x]);
if (x < length) {
  x++;
} else if (x >= length) {
  x = 0
 }
 });
})
```