# How to loop over an array of background images on click

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, events

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm making a simple app that accomplishes the following:

1. Stores objects within an array
2. Creates un-ordered list using a for loop
3. Background changes to color stored in array when corresponding list item is clicked

I completed #1 and 2, but am having trouble with 3. I reviewed [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36563946/how-to-loop-over-an-array-of-colors-to-change-background-on-keypress-down) below for assistance, but it didn't help solve the issue.

```js
// function creating un-ordered list
// it works!

function makeUL(songTitle) {
  var list = document.createElement('ul');
  for (var i = 0; i < songTitle.length; i++) {
    var track = songTitle[i];
    var trackName = track.name;
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(trackName));
        list.appendChild(node);
    }
  return list;
}
document.getElementById('song-list').appendChild(makeUL(songTitle));

// here i call the list by tag name
var listItems = document.getElementById('song-list').getElementsByTagName('li');

// here's where it gets tricky
// the click works, but it always selects the last background-image in the array
for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
  listItems[i].addEventListener("click", function changeBackground() {
      document.body.style.background = "url(" + songTitle[i].background + ") no-repeat center center fixed";
      document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to use closures. Update the `for` loop section with the provided closure.

```js
// function creating un-ordered list
// it works!

function makeUL(songTitle) {
  var list = document.createElement('ul');
  for (var i = 0; i < songTitle.length; i++) {
    var track = songTitle[i];
    var trackName = track.name;
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(trackName));
    list.appendChild(node);
  }
  return list;
}
document.getElementById('song-list').appendChild(makeUL(songTitle));

// here i call the list by tag name
var listItems = document.getElementById('song-list').getElementsByTagName('li');

// here's where it gets tricky
// the click works, but it always selects the last background-image in the array
for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    listItems[i].addEventListener("click", function changeBackground() {
      document.body.style.background = "url(" + songTitle[i].background + ") no-repeat center center fixed";
      document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
    });
  })(i);
}
```

The reason why this happens is, every time when the loop is run, `i` is incremented, but remember, the `eventListener` is not executed until you click. The conversion of `i` or usage happens only when you click. When you finally do everything, `i` will be at the `length + 1` value.

But in case of closures, the inner `i` is separated fully from the outer `i`. The value is saved and sent in a closed environment and `i` values remain the same. This means, the `i` used inside the event handler is not the same `i` of the `for` loop.